# Boost C++ Serialization and deserialization object from file recursively

Tags: c++, boost

I have a user defined "set" collection.  I have an object that contains a set of objects.  I am trying to serialize and deserialize this set of objects.

```
 class Support_Index:   used to create Element objects and insert into an OSet.
 class Element:         Collectable  - Object that has data ( just a const char* )
 class OSet:            Collectable  - collection type that holds Element objects
 class OFile:           used for the shift operator defines
```

In example code, it starts off by inserting 2 Element objects into an OSet collection.

Then calls a function that will save the OSet ( lo_terms ) to a tmp file.
The save seems to succeed.

Then calls a function to restore the contents from the file, that was just used in the save.

The issue is with the load function.  It has recursive logic, but the thing is that when executing this function, it goes through once ( with a count of objects of 1) then it comes back ( recursively ) and proceeds with a count of 2 (which is what I would have expected the first time around).  When it tries to load the 2 objects that is when I get the SEH Exception.

Program.cpp

```
bool ArchiveOSetElementsToFile(bool verbose)
{   

  const char *filename = "C:\\temp\\ArchiveOSetElementsToFile.tmp"; 
  OFile file(filename);

  IndexSupport.add_lterm("a");
  IndexSupport.add_lterm("b");    

  if (IndexSupport.lterm_entries() > 0) {         
     IndexSupport.save_lterms(file);
    }       

  IndexSupport.restore_lterms(file);        

  return passed;
}
```

OSet load

```
template<class Archive>
void load(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
  {
      std::cout << "load ASet" << std::endl;
      ar & boost::serialization::base_object<mycollect>(*this);
      boost::serialization::collection_size_type count;
      ar & count;
      std::cout << "count: " << count << std::endl;
      unsigned int i = 0;
      while (i < count)
      {
        std::cout << "load ASet Recursive Call " << std::endl;
        mycollect *thismycollect;
        ar & thismycollect;
        insert(thismycollect);
        i++;
      }
      std::cout << "loaded: " << _set.entries() << std::endl;
  }
```

Upon executing 
        ar & thismycollect;
is where it gets the SEH exception.

Things to know.  The data is coming from a file not in memory.
This is the compiler output I receive

```
output_anatom:

  load  OSet <-- derives off of myCollect class
  count: 1
  load OSet Recursive Call
  load OSet
  count: 2
  load OSet Recursive Call
```

Unhandled Exception: System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException: External component has thrown an exception.
     at _mainCRTStartup()

So.. I can't get all the code on this site so in summary.

```
 Support_Index starts the process 
 Support_Index creates Element objects and places them in an OSet collectable object.

 Support_Index call the boost save which seems to save just fine
 when Support_Index calls load it excepts on the recursive call in the load function.
```

Any ideas or help is always appreciated.

If you need anything else, please let me know.  I am sure I left out code that you might want to see.  maybe I can get that piece to you.

Comment: Why are you unable to provide a minimal complete verifiable example?

Comment: It is a bit long..  If you need it I would gladly zip it up and put it somewhere.  Has a few classes and it would make this pretty big question.  The load function is what is failing so I thought if someone already has a POC going slap it in there and see why a recursion wouldn't work.